# Using md-fab-toolbar with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-material

I am using angularJs Material in my project, and would like to use a fab-toolbar within a table that is being generated by an ng-repeat. The desired behavior is to have each fab toolbar open individually and allow actions on just that record, when they are clicked. What is happening is all of the fab toolbars are opening at once.

**Here's my controller code:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('formProject')
      .controller('inboxCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$mdDialog', 
        function inboxCtrl($scope, $window, $mdDialog) {

          $scope.itemList = [
            { assignComment: "someComment1" },
            { assignComment: "someComment2"}
          ];

          $scope.flagMenuConfig = {
            flagMenuOpen: false,
            count: 0,
            selectedDirection: 'left'
          };

        }
      ]);
})();
```

**Here's my markup:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList track by $index">

  <!-- Example column -->
  <div><strong>{{item.assignComment}}</strong></div>

  <md-fab-toolbar md-open="flagMenuConfig.isOpen" count="flagMenuConfig.count" md-direction="{{flagMenuConfig.selectedDirection}}">
    <md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
      <md-button aria-label="Flag Menu" class="md-fab md-mini">
        <md-tooltip>Flag this form</md-tooltip>
        <md-icon md-svg-src="somesvg.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </md-fab-trigger>

    <md-toolbar>
      <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">

        <md-button aria-label="Flag for self" class="md-icon-button">
          <md-tooltip>Flag this form for review by yourself</md-tooltip>
          <md-icon md-svg-src="anothersvg.svg"></md-icon>
        </md-button>

      </md-fab-actions>
    </md-toolbar>

  </md-fab-toolbar>

</div>
```

I seem to be out of ideas for today. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `flagMenuConfig` is shared between both items it seems thus you are having issue. What you may do as alternate solution is attach those handlers on individual itemList.

Comment: Well that's an idea. The item list in the real project is pulled from a sql database, and can have an indeterminate number of items. But I could stick a JSON data column in there maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, just change `md-open="this.isOpen"` initially it will render to falsy value which will close it and once you click it it will toggle isOpen value.

Here's the working demo: https://codepen.io/rikin/pen/dwYRjP?editors=1010

The way it works is each ng-repeat item will have their own individual scope. And will maintain their scope cycle of closing and opening prop values. Solution may not be what you are looking for if you are looking to toggle other open tabs upon opening another in which case solution will probably need to be crafted at controller level to attach additional props to itemList and then modify each upon individual action.

Comment: Such a simple solution! I believe this will work for me, thank you for putting that together :)